# How to structure and connect my "price" table to existing relational database table structure?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I have several tables:  `product`, `category`, `addon` in various relational relationships.

[image]

I structured it this way because:  I have many `products` that belong to their own specific `category`.  For each category there are specific `addons`.

**Price Table**

What I want to do is to add a pricing table that I will be able to query to find out things like

- (main) How much does product addon cost for this specific product.
- (optional) what is the current price for the product.  That is, I can have several prices in the table that belong to the same `product-addon`, but have different timespans (dates) of being "active".

This is the structure I am thinking of using (updated as per comments/suggestions):

[image]

Is that a good way to structure the table?  I would call this "Option 1", where "Option 2" would be to create a new table called `product_addon` as glue between `product` and `addon` and then use foreign key `product_addon_id` in my `price` table.

Comment: Would you please add ER diagrams? It's hard to understand option 2 without one.

Comment: Where do you define the M:M relationship? Isn't it already in some product_addon table? That's where the price should be.

Comment: Also ER diagrams would add context that would make it easier to understand the problems and thus help you.

Comment: in process of adding ...

Comment: How do you prevent addons that make no sense with a given product to be inserted in the table "Price"? For example ashtrays make no sense as a motorcycle addon.

Comment: You should have a table that holds what addons are possible candidates for each product, so when you creta a combo of product+addons you can only add pertinent or valid addons for that product.

Comment: my current thought on this is that the user will be responsible on keeping motorcycle ashtrays out of the table. I don't immediately visualize how to enforce that via table design or how necessary it is for my case. i.e.  If such incompatible option is somehow entered by accident, it will be removed.

Comment: I already propposed a solution that solves that in one of the several question you have posted around the price issue.

Comment: I'm slowly working though the concepts, looking at that solution, adapting it to my specific case, but not quite there yet.  Some things do not make sense to me, so I am trying to focus on smaller subproblems that hopefully will make it clearer.

Comment: the table that holds what addons are possible/available candidates for each product is the `category_addon` table.  Each product belongs to a category.  addons are 'per-category' addons and not 'per-product'.  But still - each product is connected to its available addons via the category table.

Comment: thus I could perhaps connect `product` and `category_addon` tables to my `price` table to ensure only viable options are added.  Still thinking through that though.

Comment: That won't work.  I can still specify a `product` that is incompatible with `category_addon`.  So I'm not sure how that will help.  I modeled it after your other answer and from suggestions here.  I can still use old-fashioned discipline of not inserting incompatible product options into price table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 (because it is the most simple one), but I suggest you call the link table between products and addons not "price", better call it "product_addon".

Option 2 is only necessary if you need a list of prices for the same addon in a product (whatever that would mean).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what an "addon" is.  My intuition tells me that an addon is a type of product that cannot be purchased by itself.  As such it should be represented in both the addon and product tables, and be identified by a product ID just like regular products.  The addon table would include an additional foreign key or other data which details what prerequisites are required to purchase the addon.

As for where to store price... I would suggest your model is lacking a concept of "offer."  An offer would include the product ID as a FK, and include start and end dates, plus of course the price.  Because an addon is a type of product, no additional key to the addon table would be needed.  You just need the product ID.

Comment: yes  addon is a "product option" or "product feature" or "product base or subcomponent".  It typically cannot be purchased by itself, and it has a pric.